# Problem with code for implementing REST web service in android

Tags: android, web-services

I have created two input fields using EditText, a TimePicker , a Spinner along with a submit button using basic tutorials in Android. The code for which I have mentioned in this link :
(http://ideone.com/42aYs)

I have also created a webservice using REST in netbeans which exposes a database I created in the MySQL that comes within Netbeans as per this tutorial [link] (http://netbeans.org/kb/69/websvc/rest-mysql.html) .. So now i have obtained the WSDL URL and the XML..I just need to call that values of database i created when i click submit button on phone..

How to do that? How do I show the values of the database on my phone ? What changes should I need to do for my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had good experience using Android's HttpClient to call a RESTful web service from within my app.  I referenced [this](http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/) tutorial which is extremely reusable for calling web services.  You will need to provide the REST client with the URL you are trying to access, and the resultant data will be read into the container of your choice.  It is common practice for a RESTful web service to return JSON data, so you may also be looking for a JSON->Java object parser (may I recommend [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)?)

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Btw , u saw my code right ? I have a button created.. So where do I have to write the code in the link u have given in my code ..Should I create java file for the code in your link. Also, nowhere could I see the WSDL URL present in the code u have given..So how will it come to know abt the location of my web service which is Created using REST in Netbeans..I am working on localhost..I do not plan to host it on a server..So can u suggest something for this and yeah u could recommend Google Gson..i would love to use it...just that I am new to Android :-)

Comment: It would make sense to maintain the code for the REST client as a separate class in order to promote reusability.  Also, you do not need to specify the WSDL URL to the parser itself, as the WSDL document is simply a set of definitions.  Your web service should return the data you are looking for based on the URI that you navigate to (e.g. http://localhost/item/212 returns JSON data concerning item 212).  google-gson provides an easy interface for you to parse your JSON into a Java container, provided you write a simple Java class that represents your data.

Comment: If we maintain the code for REST client in a separate java file in my Android Project .. I need to write a code within the block of code I have written for my button that will call the java file of REST client .So what changes should I do the code ? Also I want to retreive an Object ArrayList rather than a single item when I call the web service..Can u help me in this ?

Comment: You just explained to me what you need to do.  When the user clicks the button, you should formulate the URL that should be sent accessed on the web service side and then use the client to call this URL.  Your web service can return data in whatever sort of format you would like.  It makes sense to maintain consistency, however.  You can implement something like http://localhost/items returns all the items in your DB in JSON format while /items/itemid returns info only about a specific item.  You can find guides on writing web services using google, this isn't the place to ask!